# Is there only one shared preferences object per application?

Tags: android, settings, sharedpreferences

**My question is:** If I call:

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext())
```

in two different `Activities` in my application, does it refers to the same `SharedPreferences` file?

More concretely, I have a `rememberMe` check box in my `SharedPreferences`.
which I can change from two locations in my application. It looks like when I change it in one location it doesn't take effect in the second location.

**Edit:**
I have this code:

```
public View createSettingsOverlay(){
    ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.absoluteOverlay);

    LayoutInflater inflater =  getLayoutInflater();
    View result = inflater.inflate(R.layout.overlay_baloon_settings, root, false);

    ((TextView)result.findViewById(R.id.loginText)).setText(application.getCurrentlyLoggedUser());
    ((TextView)result.findViewById(R.id.passwordText)).setText(application.getCurrenlyLoggedPass());
    ((TextView)result.findViewById(R.id.loginTimeText)).setText(application.getTimeOfLogin().toString());   
    ((TextView)result.findViewById(R.id.settings_popup_server_url)).setText(application.getCurrentUrl());

    //Emil Edit 
    CheckBox rememberMe = (CheckBox)result.findViewById(R.id.cbRememberMe);
    //boolean rememberMePreference = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(DynamicDataActivity.this).getBoolean(SettingsActivity.REMEMBER_ME_CHECKBOX_KEY, false);
    Log.d(TAG, "Remember Me set in the preference is: " + PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext()).getBoolean(SettingsActivity.REMEMBER_ME_CHECKBOX_KEY, false));

    rememberMe.setChecked(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext()).getBoolean(SettingsActivity.REMEMBER_ME_CHECKBOX_KEY, false));
    rememberMe.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() 
    {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            Log.d(TAG, "boolean isChecked is: " + isChecked);
            if (isChecked)
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "Remember me checkbox in setting overlay set to True");
                PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext()).edit().putBoolean(SettingsActivity.REMEMBER_ME_CHECKBOX_KEY, true);
                application.setRememberMeChecked(true);
            }
            else
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "Remember me checkbox in setting overlay set to False");
                PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext()).edit().putBoolean(SettingsActivity.REMEMBER_ME_CHECKBOX_KEY, false);
                application.setRememberMeChecked(false);
            }
        }
    });
```

Which basically created a popup window with setting from `SharedPreferences` when I check the `rememberMe` checkbox in this popup window, close it and open it again. for some reason it is not checked again, in other `Activity` (Setting `Activity`), I can see that this change didn't took effect as well.

Comment: `It looks like when I change it in one location it doesn't take effect in the second location.` can you explain this?

Comment: Your problem is you haven't `commit`, sharedPreference will update only after `commit`

Comment: @Pragnani, stupid me, Have no idea how I missed it. you are welcome to add this as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting comments to answer,

Your problem is you haven't `commit` your preference. `SharedPreference` will update only after `commit`

Answer (score 2):

Uses this for get SharedPreferences (myPrefs is your file):

For save:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putBoolean("rememberMe", yourState);
editor.commit();
```

For get:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
boolean state = prefs.getBoolean("rememberMe", state_by_default);
```

Comment: But if I always get the defaultSharedPreferences it should refer to the same file, right?

Comment: Yes, it should be refered to the same file, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, default shared pref file is same for Application context.